# How can I say the partial finite part of looping infinite list?

Tags: math

Suppose this infinite list:

```scala
// pseudo-code
val xs0 = 1 :: 2 :: 3 :: Nil
val xs = xs0 :: xs // 1 :: 2 :: 3 :: 1 :: 2 :: ...
```

As you can see `xs` is infinite list that loops `xs0`.

but How can I say `xs0`? e.g. "`xs0` is *blahblah* of `xs`."

Are there any nice word definition?

I asked to ChatGPT to get some candidates:

- base case
- seed

Comment: ChatGPT doesn't generate answers, it generates _stories_. That's the only thing it can do, and it will make shit up in order to do so. You _cannot_ use it to find answers, the only thing you can use it for is to find inspiration. That means that if you're already great at a subject, you can ask it do so something for you and you'll be able to spot all the problems in the answer, but if you don't know what you're looking for, ChatGPT is going to give you the wrong information, and _you won't realize it's completely wrong_. ChatGPT is not, and never was, for getting factual answers.

Answer (score 1):

In "stringology", repeating part of string is called **period**

(more general thing is string factorization into `factors`)

(ex Bill Smyth. Computing patterns in strings)